# Create button from a tag with centered text

Tags: html, css

What I have is a container of a given size and a few `<a>` tags inside. Those links are all on one line and centered vertically.
Now what I want to do is specify a height for the `<a>` tags so that not only the text is clickable, but a box around it too. I managed to do it,  but unfortunately I can't make the text in the box be centered.

So I'd like to center the text in the buttons without changing the html side of things, if possible.
Here's a JSF of my current situation:

https://jsfiddle.net/ra3c3vtp/6/

html:

```
<div id=container>
    <div class=nav_list>
        <a href="">button</a>
        <a href="">button</a>
        <a href="">button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
#container {
    height: 160px;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: #ededed;
}

.nav_list {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
    padding-left: 12px;
    padding-right: 12px;
    height: 120px;
    background-color: #000000;

}
```

Comment: Always post your code in your question.

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ra3c3vtp/8/ - without knowing the height of the content inside each link, you'll have to add a placeholder element inside the `<a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The natural choice for making the text vertically aligned to the middle ("centered" vertically) is to add the CSS `vertical-align: middle`.
In this case it would not work, as it would rather try to align the whole `<a>` tag itself, rather than its contents.

What you can try instead, is to use `line-height` instead of `height`, which will make the whole line of TEXT reserve enough space vertically and align itself like you wished.

https://jsfiddle.net/ra3c3vtp/9/

Answer (score 0):

`height` is making the top and bottom space non-symmetrical. so you have to pad to both instead of assigning height to make the box tall. I replaced the `height` property with shorthand `padding` property in below. It works fine now, height is same and "button" text fits into center of the box. check yourself:

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: green;
    padding: 60px 12px; //top and bottom padding = 60px , left and right padding = 12px;

    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

oh, I added `text-align: center` and `vertical-align: middle` to make sure that it stays in center when padding changes.

Comment: That's not what I wanted though. This way the height of the box is the sum of the font size and the padding, which is harder to maintain when changing fonts.